# How can i show and hide a div properly if a radio selector is on yes?

Tags: jquery, html

Have searched google and stacked overflow and found some good suggestions, however whatever i try it doesn't work as it should. Basically i am trying to show and hide a div if a radio group is set to yes.

I have tried using classes for this to work but i can't get it to work at all, though i believe i am misunderstanding the concept.

It's worth noting that we need multiple instances of it to work as well :)

To sum up, i need 2 radio buttons for yes and no, when yes is selected, the next direct div with a class of extra-field needs to display and then hide again if the radio button is selected to no. I believe $(this) needs to be used to find the next .extra-field to show that only

I have created a jsFiddle for ease - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/GmYjd/ and have pasted code below:

HTML -

```
    <label class="label2">Do you have a 2nd Occupation?</label>
<input class="checkme" type="radio" name="22. Do you have 2nd Occupation" value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="22. Do you have 2nd Occupation" value="No" />No<br />
<div class="extra-field">
    <label class="label">Secondary Occupation?</label> <input class="textbox requiredField" name="22a. If Yes - Secondary Occupation?" type="text" />
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

and jquery -

```
// Trigger extra fields to show depending on what checkme class is clicked
    $(".checkme").on('click', function(){
        $(this).next(".extra-field").fadeToggle(500);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution I could find so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/GmYjd/8/

```
$(':radio').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next(".extra-field")
        .toggle(this.value.toLowerCase() == 'yes');
});
```

You'd have to group the radios in an element so you can specifically select the corresponding extra field.

Comment: Link to fiddle is broken. You might wanna consider fixing that for people who land on this page in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i made this easy to understand (though more codes than others).. i simply checked the clicked value of radio is it is `yes` `show` the div if no `hide` it.. and yes `input:radio` will select all radios..you can specify that with name attrbute.. but since your name is too long (which i recommend you to chnage it)..

try this

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
  if($(this).val()=='Yes'){
     $(this).siblings(".extra-field").show();  //use slideDown('slow') for effect
  }else{
     $(this).siblings(".extra-field").hide(); //use slideUp('slow') for effect
  }

});
```

and please make sure you want to use that name.... it might give you trouble while posting the form..(if you are doing so )...

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/GmYjd/6/)

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/GmYjd/9/)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work properly. If i add a second instance it drops both sets of boxes down, not the one only linked to the radio box being clicked

Comment: extra field is just a div that holds information, there is only one instance per group of radio buttons

Comment: ok.. my bad... i updated my fiddle... just add another parent div around the input and rxtrafields.. and that should work

Answer (score 0):

Made the Secondary input field invisible at first and made it display once you click yes.

```
<label class="label2">Do you have a 2nd Occupation?</label>
<input class="checkme" type="radio" name="22. Do you have 2nd Occupation" value="Yes" />
Yes
<input type="radio" name="22. Do you have 2nd Occupation" value="No" />
No
<br />
<div class="extra-field" style="display:none">
    <label class="label">Secondary Occupation?</label>
    <input class="textbox requiredField" name="22a. If Yes - Secondary Occupation?" type="text"  />
    <div class="clear">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS

```
$('.checkme').click(function() {
   if($('.checkme').is(':checked')) { 
       $(".extra-field").css("display","block")
   }
});
```

Comment: I can get it to do that, however if i add more than one group it'll mess up. I need to be able to use multiple instances. Also, i'd rather not use display block, i need it to fade toggle like in the example